# Scheduling Approvals Processing screen - Only shows 'Approve' or 'Approve All' Action - not Custom Processing Actions

Tags: processing, scheduler, acumatica

I have added some additional processing actions (Remind and Remind All) to the Tasks/Approvals screen which can generate reminder emails for approvals which are more than 24 hrs overdue.
However when I go to add a schedule to this screen - I cannot see those custom actions. I cannot see the Reject or Reject all actions either (which are standard actions)
Is this an internal restriction on the Scheduler for processing forms - ie it only shows the default Processing actions?

Is there a way I can make the custom actions visible in the Scheduler Actions Drop down? This code seems to be 'hidden'

thanks

Comment: What is the screen ID which contains your additional custom actions?

Comment: Hi Chris - it is EP503010 - Tasks/Approvals